# K2 joomla. Как вытянуть ссылку на текущую страницу вывода материалов по тегу ?

Tags: joomla, joomla3

Необходимо получить ссылку на текущий itemlist в файле шалона скк K2 joomla tag.php

такое решение не подходит:

`<a href="<?php $uri = &JFactory::getURI(); $url = $uri->toString(array('path', 'query', 'fragment')); print $url; ?>">моя ссылка</a>`

Comment: т.е вам нужна ссылка на список по определённому тегу(tag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения ссылки на список материалов по тегу, можете использовать следующую конструкцию: `index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=tag&tag={ваш тег}&task=tag`. Так же можете сгенерировать ссылку(содать новое меню с типом "K2->tag" ) в административной части сайта.

пример ссылок для фильтрации (если уже находитесь на странице с материалами)
`<a href="<?php echo JURI::current();?>?orderin=date">Сначала старые</a>`
`<a href="<?php echo JURI::current();?>?orderin=rdate">Сначала новые</a>`

Поймать активное значение:

```
    <?php
$activeItem = JRequest::getVar('orderin');
if($activeItem == 'date'){?>
    <a href="<?php echo JURI::current();?>?orderin=rdate">Сначала новые</a>
<?php }elseif($activeItem == 'rdate'){?>
    <a href="<?php echo JURI::current();?>?orderin=date">Сначала старые</a>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Идея неплохая, но все теги у меня выводятся через пункт меню. Все остальное с itemlist блокируется в robots так как куча дублей. Такого плана линк у меня отдает 404 (так как все теги через пункт меню!).

Comment: Мне нужна ссылка для того чтобы выполнить сортировку материалов в списке. К урлу у меня добавляются ?orderin="значение сортировки" сделал через <select> но не красиво <select name="" id="" class="inputbox" size="1" onchange="window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="?orderin=date" >Сначала старые</option>
<option value="?orderin=rdate" >Сначала новые</option>
</select> . Хотелось бы через a href чтобы задать стили

Comment: ну можете и по ссылкам, в ответе опишу как приблизительно

Comment: Необходимо сортировать по дате. по умолчанию сортировка установлена "сначала старые", так чтобы при добавлении новых материалов добавлялись новые страницы пагинации ?start9, ?start18 и ...т.д. Если будет сортировка "сначала новые" то на всех страницах постоянно будет меняться контент и меняться выдача ПС. Что нехорошо. А для удобства юзеров нужно сделать чтобы они могли смотреть "Сначала новые" нажав на кнопочку! В общем это очень важно! :)

Comment: посмотрели мой ответ ?

Comment: огромное спасибо! действительно работает. а та ерунда реализации что я привел в своем вопросе работала очень криво, тем более вместе с пагинацией. Я извиняюсь, еще вопрос, а не могли бы подсказать,  как сделать чтобы кнопки отображались по одной в зависимости от того какая активна. Если например выполнена сортировка "сначала старые" то отображалась только "сначала новые" . Я убрал из первой ссылки ?orderin=date, так как в такой способ сортируется по умолчанию и прекрасно работает в том варианте что вы написали!

Comment: в ответе добавлю как получить активный вариант

Comment: Что-то не получилось прикрутить последнюю правку, очень слаб в php. не могли бы более развернуто написать. спасибо большое!

Comment: вставить код PHP не получилось?

Comment: изменил код под вашу задачу.

Comment: огромное спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста )